# SwiftUI Map rotation

Tags: swift, swiftui

In this code, annotation arrow is aligned with a road heading at 340 degrees.  When the device itself/phone rotates the annotation arrow also rotates to stay aligned with the road.  How can I modify it so that the annotation arrow also stays aligned with the road when the user interacts with the map by rotating it?

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let annotations = [
        MapAnnotation(title: "Allen Rd N", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.721484, longitude: -79.446093), course: 340)
    ]

    @State private var position: MapCameraPosition = .userLocation(followsHeading: true, fallback: .automatic)
    
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Map(position: $position) {

                UserAnnotation()
  
                ForEach(annotations) { annotation in
                    
                    Annotation(annotation.title, coordinate: annotation.coordinate, anchor: .bottom) {
                        AnnotationView(annotation: annotation, offset: locationManager.trueNorthOffset)
                    }
                    .annotationTitles(.hidden)
                }
            }
            .mapStyle(.standard)
            .mapControls {
                MapUserLocationButton()
                MapCompass()
            }

        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct MapAnnotation: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let course: Double

    static func == (lhs: MapAnnotation, rhs: MapAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @Published var trueNorthOffset: Double = 0
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        checkLocationAuthorizationStatus()
        
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading() 
    }

    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        return
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        return
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        self.trueNorthOffset = newHeading.trueHeading
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() {
        let authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
        
        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        case .restricted, .denied:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }

}

struct AnnotationView: View {

    var annotation: MapAnnotation
    var offset: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: annotation.course + (360 - offset)))
    }
        
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect the map camera changing using [`.onMapCameraChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map/4231686-onmapcamerachange), then set a `@State` to the camera heading. Add an additional rotation according to this state.

```
@State private var heading: Double = 0
```

```
Map(...) {
    ...
}
.onMapCameraChange(frequency: .continuous) { context in
    heading = context.camera.heading
}
```

```
Annotation(...) {
    AnnotationView(
        annotation: annotation, 
        offset: locationManager.trueNorthOffset + heading
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, made it work as you suggested.