# change SwiftUI Map position without resetting distance?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit, core-location, mkmapcamera

How would one update the position of a SwiftUI Map without impacting the zoom (or distance from a MapCamera point of view). So want overall want

1. SwiftUI Map position being updated by incoming GPS co-ordinates from CLLocationManager
2. A user can zoom in/out themselves on the map
3. On subsequent GPS position changes I want to move the map to the new position only, and NOT change the zoom in/out (i.e. "distance" when using MapCamera) e

Issue: In my code below this is not working as when trying to get the "current distance" (aka Zoom) from MapCamera, which is "mapCamPost.camera?distance", this value seems to go to "nil" after the User zooms in the map.  How can I fix this?  Or another method with the new SwiftUI Map to solve this?   (note I didn't have this issue with UIKit MKMapCamera)

```
struct GCMap: View {
    
    @StateObject var locationMgr = GcFlightState()
    @State private var mapCamPos: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(position: $mapCamPos) {
                Annotation("UserLocation", coordinate: self.locationMgr.location.coordinate) {
                    Image(systemName: "airplane.circle").rotationEffect(.degrees(270))
                }
            }
            .onMapCameraChange() {
                print("onMapCameraChange \(mapCamPos.camera?.distance)")
            }
            .onReceive(locationMgr.$location) { location in
                mapCamPos =  .camera(MapCamera(
                    centerCoordinate: location.coordinate,
                    distance: mapCamPos.camera?.distance ?? 1000,   // <<===
                    heading: location.course
                ))
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need an extra `@State` that you set in `onMapCameraChange`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77765141/5133585). You basically do that, but with `distance` instead of `heading`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can track the camera's `distance` using an extra `@State`:

```
@State private var distance = 1000.0
```

```
.onMapCameraChange(frequency: .continuous) {
    distance = $0.camera.distance
}
```

Then you can use `distance` when creating the new `MapCamera`.

Comment: how should I be using the `distance`. I have my code like this: 
```
        .onChange(of: plane.lon) {
            withAnimation(.smooth(duration:  3.5)) {
                location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: plane.lat ??  0, longitude: plane.lon ??  0)
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: distance, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta:  0.3, longitudeDelta:  0.3))
                cameraPosition = .region(region)
            }
        } 
```
How can I keep the same user zoom level by using the distance variable when latitudeDelta is what is deciding the zoom?